# Spring Boot + Spring Session HttpSessionListener not working

Tags: spring-mvc, session, spring-boot, spring-session

I have a spring boot (1.3.2) app in which I have implemented a HttpSessionListener. I registered the listener from a @Configration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class ApplicationSessionConfiguration {

@Bean
public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionListener> sessionListener() {
    return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionListener>(new SessionListener());
}
```

}

I have debugged into ServletListenerRegistrationBean.onInitialize method and the listener is getting registered with the ServletContext. Problem is now when I make a dummy REST call to the app the session gets created properly and sent back as a SESSION cookie, but the HttpSessionListener.createSession method never gets called. I am not sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the feature you need is not yet released in a stable build. However as per [this ticket](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/4#issuecomment-130462594) this is fixed and is available in 1.1.0 M1 release for spring-session. You may want to try 1.1.0.RC1 release of spring-session to see if this helps what you want. Exact details on how to get this done can be found [in this doc link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html5/#httpsession-httpsessionlistener)

In case using 1.1.0.RC1 release is NOT an option (or if you prefer not use RC1 due to what ever reason), you can still intercept session creation and destroy events by extending default CookieHttpSessionStrategy with you own implementation (say MyCookieHttpSessionStrategy) and then overriding the onNewSession(..) and onInvalidateSession(..) to intercept these events. Register MyCookieHttpSessionStrategy as normal bean and you are all set (it'll be automatically picked up by Redis session repository). This works just fine with Redis sessions, I am using these events in my spring boot web app this way.

Hope this helps!!